# read attributes of server file

Tags: iphone

i am using following code to access properties of local file.
[CODE]
attrs = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:originalFilePath error:NULL];
[/CODE]

is there any similar method by which i can read the attributes of server file?

kindly help me to solve this problem.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Those [attributes](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Attribute_Keys) are specific to a file stored through an attached file system. The attributes you retrieve for a server file would probably depend on the client for the protocol you are using (web service, AFP, etc.) and how the data are cached in your application's sandbox.